# How to override a function in an inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I would like to implement a widget system similar to FLTK using python in a 3D world.
I simplified my code to the following. I don't get the correct answer. The function is not overwritten even if I change the variable.

```
def callbacks():
    print("callback")
    
def create():
    print ("override")

def default():
    print("default")


class f1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test=default
        pass
    def docallback(self):
        self.test()

        
class f2(f1):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test=create
        super().__init__()

class f3(f2):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test=callbacks
        super().__init__()
    

t1=f1()
t2=f2()
t3=f3()

t1.docallback()
t2.docallback()
t3.docallback()
```

Comment: Your `f3` class overwrites its setting of `self.test` by calling `super().__init__()`.

Comment: This isn't multiple inheritance. Multiple inheritance would be if `f3` had both `f1` and `f2` as immediate parent classes: `class f3(f1, f2)`.

Comment: Also, there is no multiple inheritance going on here...

Comment: I suggest that you add more `print()` statements to understand how your code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be calling `super().__init__()` first in this case:

```py
class f1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = default

    def docallback(self):
        self.test()

        
class f2(f1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.test = create

class f3(f2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.test = callbacks
```

These 'constructors' call `super().__init__()` first (which makes assignments to `self.test`), but then immediately assigns the correct value to `self.test` itself.

Comment: Thank you very much .. Simple solution. This works. But please, would you explain why?

Answer (score 3):

`f1.__init__` should use `default` as the default value of a parameter, not a hard-coded assignment.

```
class f1:
    def __init__(self, test=default):
        self.test = test
```

Then `f2` and `f3` can simply provide *different* arguments when using `super()`.

```
class f2:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(create)


class f3:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(callbacks)
```

Comment: Why not hardcoded? as any variable holding a function shouldn't that works?

Comment: The only reason to use `super` at all is if I assume there is other code in `f1.__init__` that you have just omitted from the example. You should parameterize `f1.__init__` so that it can be used to set `self.text` for any class or subclass, rather than duplicating the assignment `self.test = ...` in every subclass.

Comment: If you want, you can look at my github. It is a big project for FreeCAD. https://github.com/MariwanJ/Design456/tree/devbranch/ThreeDWidgets